# Adding colon along with custom title to tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, tcblisting

Sorry that the question description isn't great, but what I mean is how can you update the settings to support having either a title that's just default from the tcbcounter like `Example 1.1` or something more descriptive like `Example 1.1: Making a tcolorbox` - something to help distinguish examples apart and give descriptions so I can easily come back to them later.

I've currently updated this tcolorbox to support both listings and text/comments; however, I would also like to make the title work like what I described above. Here is the code for the box (with examples working [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620837/tcolorbox-with-theorem-and-lstlisting)):

```
\newtcblisting[auto counter, number within=section, list inside=examplelist]{tcbexample}[2][]{%
        colback=gray!5, colbacktitle=gray!40, coltitle=black,
        frame hidden, arc=2pt, titlerule=0pt, toptitle=2pt, bottomtitle=2pt,
        fonttitle=\bfseries, breakable, enhanced, parbox=false,
        segmentation style={solid, draw=gray!20, line width=1pt}, % personal update
        comment and listing,
        title=Example~\thetcbcounter,
        comment={#2},#1
}
```

[image]

Is there some way the settings for the tcolorbox could be altered to change the title so that it can reflect something more descriptive like `Example 1.1: Making a tcolorbox` (but when such input is left empty, it defaults to `Example 1.1`? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove colon from title bar in tcolorbox theorem without a title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137515/remove-colon-from-title-bar-in-tcolorbox-theorem-without-a-title)

Comment: ... actually on closer look there's a slight difference (theorem versus listing)...

Comment: Good call, I'll add that now. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Thanks for the input - I'm terrible at coming up with title names so sometimes it might not be descriptive enough. I'll try to improve my questions in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `after title` key:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable, listings, skins}

\newtcblisting[auto counter, number within=section, list inside=examplelist]{tcbexample}[2][]{%
        colback=gray!5, colbacktitle=gray!40, coltitle=black,
        frame hidden, arc=2pt, titlerule=0pt, toptitle=2pt, bottomtitle=2pt,
        fonttitle=\bfseries, breakable, enhanced, parbox=false,
        segmentation style={solid, draw=gray!20, line width=1pt}, % personal update
        comment and listing,
        title=Example~\thetcbcounter,
        comment={#2},#1
}

\pgfkeysifdefined{/tcb/name}{\fail}{
  \tcbset{
    name/.style={after title={: #1}}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\section{title}
\begin{tcbexample}[name=title]{comment}
code
\end{tcbexample}

\begin{tcbexample}{no title}
code
\end{tcbexample}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`tcolorbox` has a built-in logic for this kind of appending an "optional name" to title (also check the key `separator sign`), but unfortunately it's hard-coded in the internal of `\tcbnewtheorem` (more specifically, [`\tcb@theo@title`](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/blob/e25e8f51ff49417ff96d0435f7bbd9483f321dfe/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbtheorems.code.tex#L35-L45)), hence will only apply for `tcolorbox`-defined theorem environments.

Comment: Thanks! Would adding the name attribute would be a global change, i.e. it would work for all boxes?

Comment: @Revise Yes, every `tcolorbox`-defined box can use `name` option.